# Set Kestrel Output Color from ILogger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, console, kestrel

I noticed when setting different logging levels in ASP.NET Core, that sometimes the logging output generated by different calls to Entity Framework among other things, the console ForeColor changes to yellow, red, blue, etc...

I thought it would be nice to be able to do custom colors to this window (just to make the stuff I am putting into the log output stand out a little better as a message sent to the ILogger from my code)

I tried setting the color this way (just to see if it would work)...

```
//set the console color (expecting the Kestrel console window to change to this)
var oldColor = Console.ForeColor;
Console.ForeColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow

//send the log message (expecting it to be yellow when output in the kestrel console window)
_logger.LogTrace(@"Hello World!");

//be a good citizen and set the color back now that the log message has been displayed
Console.ForeColor = Console.ForeColor;
```

Unfortunately it's not this simple, I must have to do this in either the Factory or there is something else in the ILogger that will let me do it - I figured I would ask here before I started digging around in the Entity Framework Core code to see how they (Microsoft) is doing it.

I tried searching for some info on this topic here on SO and MSDN - I didn't come up with anything, so I will apologize in advance if it's already been answered and I was just looking in the wrong places.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code for EF Core is in class called `ConsoleLoggerProvider`. Colors are hardcoded and depend on the `LogLevel`. Try calling `LogInformation` (DarkGreen) or `LogWarning` (Yellow) instead of `LogTrace`

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of what different colors you are referring to?

Comment: See https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console

Comment: [Serilog.Sinks.Console](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-console) does something nice if you use format string and parameters, but again it is not you that decides how it is displayed... and if you want to stay compatible with ILogger, there isn't much you can do without impacting other ILogger implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The colours in ILogger implementation are decided based on the LogLevel that is being logged. If you want to specify the colours yourself you would need to implement ILogger yourself. It's a pretty simple interface but as a reference this post gives you an example.

http://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2017/05/05/add-custom-logging-in-aspnetcore.html

Also, if you want to go all out, there's a nice library that wraps Console so you can switch the colours a bit easier than having to keep setting `ForegroundColour` here http://colorfulconsole.com/

Comment: Note that while implementing a logger yourself is pretty straight forward, writing a performant console logger is not a trivial task. Apart from that, the logging interface is meant to be provider-independent, so adding formatting mechanisms that only work for that one custom logger is likely not a good idea. Also also, one should use structural logging to highlight individual values; if that’s not enough metadata, maybe your logging calls are a bit too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Down the line, ILogger can support what you want but you won't be able to use some ILogger extension methods since those are more restrictives on what you can do, but you could add your own extension methods to help you. Here is the signature of ILogger.

```
void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, 
    Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter);
```

So you would have to create your custom ILogger implementation and use EventId to decide the color based on that...

Also if you want to go all in and color some parts of the string, you could use a combination of `TState` and `formatter` that works for 'standard' ILogger but you could extract additional information in your custom ILogger and format the message the way you like it.  As noted by @poke, writing a state of the art console logger can be challending... but you could inspire yourself from the 'standard' console logger implementation [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Logging/Logging.Console/src/ConsoleLogger.cs).